# Version control for designs in Sketch

Tags: file-management

I'm looking to implement version control across my team and I need a starting point.

Criteria I need:

- Something that integrates well with our software stack: Sketch and Zeplin
- Stored in the cloud
- Shows previews of the files

I've looked at Git but as far as I've seen it doesn't let me preview files to see whats in them, is there something that does this?

Comment: The answers in that question are relevent to photoshop, Sketch is alot more open and has more integrations so I'd be keen to hear out answers relating specifically to Sketch. Not to mention that it was asked over 5 years ago around the same time Sketch was released.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### **Lucky for you there are a bunch of options from paid to free.**

---

[image]

Starting off there's [Plant](https://plantapp.io/) that has free and pro tiers and is in open beta.

---

[image]

Next there's [Abstract](https://www.goabstract.com/) which also has free and pro tiers and is also in open beta.

---

[image]

Additionally [Folio](http://folioformac.com/) exists but it's not as solid of an option in my opinion as the others.

---

[image]

Finally there's my favorite which is [Kactus](https://kactus.io/); which also has a nice [github page](https://github.com/kactus-io/kactus).

---

Now what you chose all comes down to your workflow.

- Abstract is good if you are already familiar with Git. Abstract also does a nice job at visualising the timelines and "commits".
- Kactus works to bring together designers and developers onto a shared
  workflow and platform in GitHub. Kactus aims to bring designers on
  board to have an integrated design process
- Plant, unlike Abstract and Kactus which use a branching model for
  collaboration,   only shows a linear history. Using the known
  paradigm of uploading/downloading changes, Plant has created a simple
  and elegant solution that would satisfy many people.

---

Find what **you** like and what works for **your** workflow!

Comment: @OwenHughes No problem!