# What is an effective process to control versions in Abstract?

Tags: file-management

I'm currently looking at introducing [Abstract](https://www.goabstract.com/) version control to our team.

I'm keen to know how people manage a large amount of files in it (in Active and in Archive). We have a team of designers, so you can imagine this generates a large amount of Sketch files when we work on various projects.

What do people do to manage the amount of files in it especially if it is alot, and how do they cope if they need to go back to one in a long list of files?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Version Control for Designers / Alternative to Version Cue](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13161/version-control-for-designers-alternative-to-version-cue)

Comment: This is not a duplicate, the question you posted is asking for alternatives to a version control software. I am asking how people deal with large amounts of files and their structures with in Abstract and how teams deal with it and use it. It was also asked 5 years ago before Sketch and Abstract where even created.

Comment: @OwenHughes I've edited your question to make it a bit more precise, please feel free to roll back or let me know if you deem this version doesn't fit your initial intention :)

Comment: Relevant background: https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/109433/version-control-for-designs-in-sketch