# Is there a version control software tool that works on Windows?

Tags: software-recommendation

I'm working with a team that uses Windows, Axure & Illustrator.  I was hoping that I could find some sort of tool similar to Kactus or Abstract for version control, but I can't seem to find anything for Windows or for Adobe Illustrator.  Does anybody have any suggestions?

Comment: After a quick search over on [Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29292/version-control-for-graphics) I found a reference to Alienbrain Asset Management.  I can't make a recommendation having never tried it, but it's for mac and windows.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Version control for designs in Sketch](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/109433/version-control-for-designs-in-sketch) and [Version Control for Designers / Alternative to Version Cue](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/questions/13161/version-control-for-designers-alternative-to-version-cue)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with Kactus or Abstract, but I will say you could always use a tool like Git. It's generally used for source code, but there's no reason it couldn't work on design documents. There are some good GUIs that could help streamline the process

Comment: Or instead of git you could use mercurial that has a slightly better large binary file support.

Comment: This is got a bit long, so bear with me. One issue with this idea is that I don't think there are any standalone diff tools for windows or even mac that support .ai. Or it's not really a diff tool that you need, just a simple preview. I've only seen preview support for .ai files in these designer oriented version control applications, in which previewing these different versions is typically way easier too.

Comment: [Folio for mac](http://folioformac.com/) is a good example of that. Just like Kactus, it uses Git. Folio definitely has its own issues, but it does many things right. The interface is very simple: list of projects, list of project files, list of versions for the selected file. Hovering over each version shows you a preview. It also has a full-size preview. Whenever you save your .ai file in Illustrator you get a notification asking if you wish to save a version of the file in Folio.

Comment: If you used any regular graphical interface for Git and you wanted to preview every single version, you'd need to go through every single commit and open the files with Illustrator, at which point saving separate .ai files might be better. The point isn't that designers absolutely need to preview every single version all the time, but without a simple preview, it'll be difficult to find a specific version if the only thing you have to go is a text description. You'd just be picking commits somewhat randomly trying to find that specific version.